# concurrency in asynchronous and synchronous pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, vert.x

We have a servlet based application, which serve the request synchronously, and each request will take almost `4000ms` since it have to execute a lot of sql queries to a remote database and do a lot of calculation jobs.

We using `ab` to test the application, the concurrency and throughput is rather small.

In my opinion, in the traditional servlet model, the request is served synchronously: a thread is created for each request, and this thread will wait until if the process is done, which means in my case this servlet thread will wait for `4000ms`, during the hang time, it can not do anything. A kind of waste of resources.

At the sometime, I am interested in `vertx`, so I write the application based on `vertx`. I know the `event loop` model in `vertx` which can not be blocked. So the block job(which will take `4000ms` is executed in the worker thread like this:

```
router.route().blockingHandler(context -> {
    List result=new ArrayList();


    String[] layers = getLayers(context);
    final int[] len=new int[]{layers.length};
    layers.forEach(l_>{
        context.vertx().executeBlocking(f->{
            List d = doDataseJob(l);
            d = doCalculationJob(d)
            f.complete(d);
        },false,r->{
            len[0]--;
            result.addAll(r.result())
            if(len[0]==0){
                //all blocking jobs have done
                //return
                context.response().end(.......);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

However after test the concurrency by `ab` again, we found there are only a little improvement compared with the servlet based app.

AFAIK, the response time for a single request will not change too much between asynchronous and synchronous pattern, however the `throughput` and `concurrency` should be improved in asynchronous pattern(the vertx based app), since the `event loop` thread which just forward the request can serve more requests than before.

Do I miss anything? Or I use `vertx` wrong ?

---

Update 1: make the heavy job return `Future`:

```
@Override
public Future doHeavyJob(String layer) {
    Future future = Future.future();
    new Thread(()->{
        List d = doDataseJob(tile, layer, future);
        d = doCalculationJob(d);
        future.complete(d)
    }).start();
    return future;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in another topic, you're using Vert.x in a wrong manner.
There's no concurrency gain, since you're doing exactly what your servlet were doing before: putting a very long job on a thread pool.
The fact that to put the job on this pull you use EventLoop doesn't change anything. It may even worsen it a bit, since Vert.x worker thread pool is quite small by default, 20 threads. If you had your servlet container configured with more threads, it would outperform Vert.x in that setup, actually.

What you should do instead:

- If there are independent queries, do them in parallel, combining their results using Futures
- Wrap your DAOs in verticles, and communicate using EventBus

Do note, that if you have queries of up to 4s, your DB will become the bottleneck once you resolve those issues.

Comment: Thanks, you have answered my another question. Did you mean that when I using `executeBlocking` or `blockingHanlder`, the job will be done in the `worker thread` pools which have a limited size which in turn can result in the heavy job put in queue? If this is true, if I create a new thread myself may be fine? Since using the `Future` is a kind of custom thread in my opinion.

Comment: And furthermore, does  the `worker thread` pool make any sense in vertx?

Comment: Creating another thread will only postpone your problem. Each thread takes 1Mb by default to begin with. You'll quickly run out of memory. Future, on the other hand, doesn't create a thread. Worker pool is good for long running processes that don't concern the user. This is not your case.

Comment: Thanks. I want to make sure one thing: the `Future` you mentioned is the `Future` in jdk or `Future` in vertx. And any example for this kind of usage?

Comment: You can see an example here: https://github.com/AlexeySoshin/VertxAnswers/blob/master/src/main/java/handler/LongOperatingVerticle.java#L21

Comment: Thanks, this is wrapping my dad in vertices, how about run them in parallel ？

Comment: See my update, I return a `Future` object for the database job.

Comment: If you're using Vert.x, you shouldn't start threads by yourself.

Comment: Sorry, but how can you return a `Future` without starting threads by myself ?

Comment: You don't need a separate thread to handle Future. Vert.x does that for you.